linux shell: How to extract substrings separated by semicolon from a file using sed regex
I have a file with below content:
10|subpath ; xxx ; xxx ; xxx ; xxx ; substring ; xxx ; ......
12|subpath ; xxx ; xxx ; xxx ; xxx ; substring ; xxx ; ......
18|subpath ; xxx ; xxx ; xxx ; xxx ;  ; xxx ; ......

I want to use sed to extract:

the content before 1st semicolon
the 'substring' between 5th and 6th semicolons (the 'substring' can be any string and can also be nothing, and there could be space between 'substring' and its pre-/post- semicolons).

After extraction, i want to get things like
10|subpath;substring_fs
12|subpath;substring_fs
18|subpath;fs

if 'substring' has nothing/empty, then put 'fs' there. if 'substring' non-emtpy, then append '_fs' to 'substring'

your rules don't match your output - it seems you want to also strip trailing whitespace from content before 1st semicolon

Unless there is a specific reason to use a particular tool, you should always treat with skepticism any plan to use a particular tool.  Often, there is a better tool to do the job, and you limit yourself by ending a question with "using tool X".  For this particular problem, I would put sed at around the 4th position on the list of tools to consider.

sed -E '
    # strip leading/trailing whitepace for simplicity
    s/[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*/;/g

    # extract relevant fields
    s/^([^;]*)(;[^;]*){4}(;[^;]*).*/\1\3/

    # append _ if required
    s/[^;]$/&_/

    # append fs
    s/$/fs/
' file


For completeness, an Awk solution:
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";"} { gsub(/ *; */, ";") }{ print $1, $6 ($6 ? "_": "") "fs" }' file


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's/\s*;\s*/\n/g
     s#.*#echo "&" | sed -nE "1p;6{s/\\S+/\&_/;s/$/fs/;p}"#e
     y/\n/;/' file

Replace any ;'s with or without spaces either side with newlines.
Using substitution and the e evaluation flag, invoke a second invocation of sed where each field in the original line is now a line.
The second sed invocation invokes the -n and -E options.

Print the first line (the id and subpath).

For line 6 (field 6):

If line is not empty, append _.

Append fs.

Print.




Finally replace all newlines by ;'s and print the results.
N.B. In the second sed invocation, certain metacharacters must be escaped.
